# Pythonic way to re-map a data structure

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I am given data structures like `Data` here:

```
Data.whatever.t       # (contains time)
Data.whatever.log.vel # (contains velocity)
Data.a                # (contains acceleration)
```

and I want to map them to a an object in an elegant/pythonic way, so that I have:

```
data.t
data.velocity
data.acceleration
```

I am thinking of creating using a json file to hard-code the mappings, e.g.:

```
{
  "Data": [
     {
       "t": "whatever.t",
       "velocity": "whatever.log.vel",
       "acceleration": "a",
     },
  ]
}
```

but I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use __dict__. Like Data.__dict__

Comment: How are you "given" this structure?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a [proxy class](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy) for changing the interface of a structure, which sounds like what you are after.

Depending on how you are "given" this structure (which looks like a class with class attributes pointing to other objects) you can take it as an argument to your class, or instantiate yourself. For example if you are passed this structure as input:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace # for mimicking your "Data" structure

# creating this:
# Data.whatever.t       # (contains time)
# Data.whatever.log.vel # (contains velocity)
# Data.a                # (contains acceleration)

Data = SimpleNamespace(
    a='someacceleration',
    whatever=SimpleNamespace(
        t='sometime',
        log=SimpleNamespace(
            vel='somevelocity'
        )
    )
)

# Relevant part of solution
class ProxyClass:
    def __init__(self, somedata):
        self._proxy_data = somedata
        self.t = self._proxy_data.whatever.t
        self.velocity = self._proxy_data.whatever.log.vel
        self.acceleration = self._proxy_data.a
```

#### Demo:

```
In [2]: Data
Out[2]: namespace(a='someacceleration', whatever=namespace(log=namespace(vel='somevelocity'), t='sometime'))

In [3]: data = ProxyClass(Data)

In [4]: data.acceleration
Out[4]: 'someacceleration'

In [5]: data.velocity
Out[5]: 'somevelocity'

In [6]: data.t
Out[6]: 'sometime'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should learn the [python class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#) first.

**A simple demo:**

```
class T(object):
    pass
class Velocity(object):
    pass
class Acceleration(object):
    pass
class Data(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = T()
        self.velocity = Velocity()
        self.acceleration = Acceleration()


data = Data()
print(data.t)
print(data.velocity)
print(data.acceleration)
```